# How to get custom list template id?

Tags: 2013, survey-list

I searched everywhere, but could not find a solution that worked for me.

We've created a default survey, changed it a bit and saved it as a new ESS Survey template from the user interface. I can create surveys based on this template successfully.

However, I have some C# code that creates a survey name automatically for me. It is now based on the template ID is "102", which is the default survey. I want to create the survey in code based on my custom survey.

I understood that I need a custom list template ID (which should be > 10000), but I cannot find out how I can find the custom list template id's. I found commands that list the default list template id's (i.e. 100, 101) but not the custom survey template ID's. How can I find the custom surveytemplate ID's?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can check a list by ID, but you can check the "BaseTemplate" property.

```
SPList list = web.Lists["List ID"];
    SPListTemplateType type = list.BaseTemplate;

    if(type == SPListTemplateType.Tasks){
    //Do something for a Task List
    }else if(type == SPListTemplateType.Survey)
    {
    //Do something for a Survey List
    }
```

If this solution don't solve your problem, this is a walkaround:

First, you have to change your list creation code, adding a property bag to them. This will be a "flag" to check if is a custom survey list:

After create the new list, do this:

```
if(!list.RootFolder.Properties.ContainsKey("CustomListCheck"){
 list.RootFolder.Properties.Add("CustomListCheck", true);
}
```

Now, checking the list:

```
if(list.RootFolder.Properties.ContainsKey("CustomListCheck"){
bool isCustom = list.RootFolder.Properties["CustomListCheck"];
 if(isCustom == true){
  //Do something...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it using Object-Model-Browsers like SharePoint-Manager 2013 (available via Codeplex)

But I don´t know, if your list gets a custom templateId at all, if you are generating your template using the "Save As Template"-Option via the GUI. If it does, however, the base List, from which you generated the template will still have it´s original, built-in ID. Only new Lists would get the new BaseTemplateID

Besides: Maybe you should consider deploying a Template with fixed ID using a Feature. Because if you Change something in your base-List and generate a new Template, it will (if it does so) get a new templateId. And then you might have to Change your code again.